# Refresh AccessToken in Loopback 3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I recently started a project in LoopBack3 and I am using the integrated loopback authentication and I need to refresh AccessToken once ttl time is up.

I have searched the loopback documentation and on the internet but I haven't found a way to do it. I tried to make a middleware in server/server.js and make a query directly with the connector (MySql) and update the field "created" but it seemed to do the update without errors but it doesn't change the values in the database

```
// Array with the paths that I want to apply the middleware
var aPaths = [...];

//Middleware in server.js
app.use(aPaths,async function (req, res, next) {
  const connector = app.dataSources.myDataSource.connector;
  if (!req.headers.authorization || req.headers.authorization == '') {

    return res.status(403).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });

  }else{

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM AccessToken where id = '" + req.headers.authorization + "'";
    connector.execute(sql, null, async (err, resultObject) => {

      if (!err && resultObject) {
        if (resultObject.length > 0) {

          const date1 = new Date(Date.now());
          const date2 = new Date(String(resultObject[0].created));
          var diffTime = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());

          // Difference between the creation date and the current date (In minutes)
          diffTime = diffTime / (1000 * 60);

          // Token validity in minutes
          var token_validity = resultObject[0].ttl / 60;

          // If the token is still valid, do nothing
          if (token_validity > diffTime) {
            next();
          }else{
            // If the token expired in less than 10 minutes I want to refresh it
            if ((diffTime - token_validity) < 10) {
              var sql = "UPDATE AccessToken SET created= NOW() WHERE id = '" + req.headers.authorization + "'";
              console.log("SQL: " + sql);
              try {
                await connector.execute(sql, null, (err) =>{
                    if (error){
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.status(401).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                });
              } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(401).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });
              }
            } else {
              return res.status(401).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });
            }
          }
        } else {
          return res.status(401).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });
        }
      } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ error : {code:'AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED',statusCode:401} });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I want to update the token if it is expired in less than 10 minutes but with this i get:

Error: Invalid Access Token

because it continues with the next() and the token is deleted by loopback because is expired

Answer (score 0):

Just update created field in accessToken table against a particular user.

Go to server.js file and update the following code :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 if (!req.accessToken) {
   return next();
 }

if (your condition)) {
  req.accessToken.created =new Date();
  req.accessToken.save(next);
}
});
```

Comment: I tried with a middleware registered in the middleware.json (before the auth and after the loopback middleware loopback#token), but loopback authentication continues marking the token as invalid

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to consider to refresh your accessToken as long as accessToken is not expired. if you only refresh the accessToken when it is expired in less than 10 minutes users will be logged out when there are no actions for ten minutes.

server.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  let token = req.accessToken;
  if (!token) return next(); 

  let now = new Date();
  // for performance, you can drop it
  if (now.getTime() - token.created.getTime() < 6000) return next();
  token.updateAttribute('created', now, next);
});
```

you don't need to execute SQL queries but instead this code should work.
also if you want to change default `ttl` you can set it in your `model-config`

model-config.json

```
...
"user": {
  "dataSource": "mysqlDs",
  "public": true,
  "options": {
    "ttl": 1209600
  }
},
...
```